# how to solve connection issue in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

http://127.0.0.1:27017/ when I am trying access the server I am getting

> It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.

How can I solve this please help me I am new to mongodb.
When I am trying to access from terminal I can get the data

```
db.restaurants.find()
 { "_id" : ObjectId("5658acd43132e79a3b88e510"), "address" : { "street" : "2 Avenue", "zipcode" : "10075", "building" : "1480", "coord" : [ -73.9557413, 40.7720266 ] }, "borough" : "Manhattan", "cuisine" : "Italian", "grades" : [ { "date" : ISODate("2014-10-01T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 11 }, { "date" : ISODate("2014-01-16T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "B", "score" : 17 } ], "name" : "Vella", "restaurant_id" : "41704620" }
```

Comment: Think you should use this format : mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options...');
not just the host:port

Comment: What do you mean truly accessing the server. You cannot access mongo server from your browser

Comment: can exaplain clearly

Comment: See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: As @SarathNair mentioned, you merely accessing from browser (ie, over http), which is not a proper way to access against mongodb. Just use clients like mongoose or something else to connect it.